# Tomcat 7 giving error when i run spring + mvc on tomcat,At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs

Tags: spring, tomcat7

Getting the same error.

Please kindly let me know what are the paths and from where i can download the spring related jar files.

**my controller code.**

```
package MySpringMVCProjects;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class HelloController implements Controller {
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        Map m = new HashMap();
        m.put("msg", "Hello" + name);
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("success", m);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Wen i run the start.

> Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
>           WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SimpleWebService' did not find a matching property.
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
>           WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FirstMVCHelloWorld' did not find a matching property.
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.64
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: Server built:          Aug 19 2015 17:18:06 UTC
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: Server number:         7.0.64.0
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: OS Version:            6.3
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: Architecture:          amd64
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_75-b13
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\gafg\Desktop\IVP.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\gafg\Desktop\IVP.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\gafg\Desktop\IVP.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
>           INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/amd64;C:\app\gafg\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\;C:\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle\bin\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\jdk1.7\bin;.;;C:\Users\gafg\Documents\Eclipse - Kepler\Eclipse-Kepler\eclipse;;.
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>           INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8001"]
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>           INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>           INFO: Initialization processed in 746 ms
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
>           INFO: Starting service Catalina
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
>           INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.64
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
>           INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\gafg\Desktop\IVP.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\FirstMVCHelloWorld\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:21 AM org.apache[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn5LQ.png).catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
>           INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:22 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
>           INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\gafg\Desktop\IVP.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SimpleWebService\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
>           INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>           INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8001"]
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>           INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
>           Oct 09, 2015 11:09:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>           INFO: Server startup in 2756 ms

[image: ScreenShot]

- List item

Java Controller Code : under src folder.
JSP code under : web-content/jsp folder.
web.xml file : under web-inf/ folder
serverl.xml file : under lib folder.

Still i am facing this issue. Please kindly some one help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple warning , it indicates that there were some jars that could not be scanned for improving JSP compilation time. The reason you get a 404 might be a spring configuration problem , so you cannot access your web page.
From the snippet you posted , is your controller picked up by spring ? cause you haven't annotated the class and you haven't posted your spring-conf.xml to check if your controller gets wired up

Comment: this is my spring.xml file.

Comment: <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
<!--  controller -->
<bean name = "/hello.htm" class = "MySpringMVCProjects.HelloController" />
<!--  view resolver -->
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name = "prefix" value ="/" />
        <property name = "suffix" value =".jsp" />
</bean>

Comment: i am not so sure if the code you posted is working , check this tutorial here http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-annotation-javaconfig-full-example/

Comment: please could you suggest where i can download spring MVC related jar files.if you know the link , kindly share with me.

Comment: you aint using maven ? as suggested in the tutorial?

Comment: No i am not using maven.

Comment: then you ll have to download all the dependencies by yourself , which will be a hard task to do. so I recommend start using maven , otherwise you could find a spring project at github / bitbucket , clone it , so you ll get all the dependencies and hold them in a local directory or find one by one the jars required by spring mvc